# How to make navigation drawer only closable from border

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a list view in my navigation and while I am scrolling down or up my list view I accidentally close drawer too. I don't want my users to face that issue. How can I make drawer only closable from border like it opens only from border?

Comment: What is `Closable from border`? Is it with swipe gesture or from the actionbar tap?

Comment: When you want to open the drawer you should swipe from border of the screen. But when you want to close it you are able to swipe anywhere on drawer to close it. I want it only closable with swipes which starts from the border of the drawer.